# Is it safe to change the password of a PostgreSQL read replica on AWS RDS?

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

Is it safe to change the password of a PostgreSQL read replica on AWS RDS? I would like to use the read replica to download database snapshots on my laptop but don't want to have the master database password there.

It currently has the same password as the master database and I only use it for offline analytics (e.g. nothing important uses it).

Comment: Did you ever find the answer to this question?

Comment: I don't believe I did!

Comment: Contacted support and they told me no, unfortunately.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I contacted AWS support, and after a lengthy exchange the answer is **no**: you must use the same password for postgres master/slave DBs. The support rep hinted that it may be possible with other DB types, though.